# Youtube: api/stats/qoe metrics

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am researching Youtube APIs, backend calls like "watchtime", "api/stats/qoe". I am unable to find definitions of the query string metrics.

For example,
I got these metrics from "api/stats/qoe", but I don't know what they mean?

```
fmt: 244
afmt: 251
cpn: 53sXf1ssOnU0CWnv
ei: unq1X4-zMdyN8wTS5aKACQ
el: detailpage
docid: 5HVHnUmRL6U
ns: yt
fexp: 23735347%2C23744176%2C23804281%2C23839597%2C23856950%2C23857949%2C23868322%2C23882502%2C23884386%2C23890959%2C23895671%2C23911055%2C23915993%2C23918597%2C23927767%2C23927767%2C23934970%2C23935844%2C23940248%2C23940704%2C23942338%2C23942633%2C23944779%2C23945479%2C23946420%2C23948841%2C23951620%2C23955372%2C23956524%2C23958572%2C23958692%2C23961732%2C23964530%2C23965224%2C23965756%2C23966254%2C23966412%2C23966725%2C23967043%2C23968560%2C23968756%2C23970847%2C23970974%2C23972773%2C24500568%2C24590298%2C24631715%2C24631744%2C3300106%2C3300131%2C3300164%2C3313321%2C3318700%2C3318773%2C3318889%2C3319220%2C3320540%2C3329303%2C9449243
cl: 342543027
seq: 3
cbr: Chrome
cbrver: 86.0.4240.198
c: WEB
cver: 2.20201117.01.00
cplayer: UNIPLAYER
cos: Windows
cosver: 10.0
cmt: 0.762:0.000,1.012:0.011,1.943:0.924,10.039:9.020
vps: 0.762:B,1.012:PL,10.039:PL
user_intent: 0.031
bwm: 10.039:3241322:1.280
bwe: 10.039:2551061
bat: 10.039:1:1
vis: 10.039:3
bh: 10.039:30.764
df: 10.039:0
```

Can someone point me in the right direction where I can get definitions of these metrics? I am specifically looking for watch start time & watch end time of a video.

Answer (score 1):

Some fields I can get from the name or data:

- fmt: ?
- afmt: ?
- cpn: ?
- ei: ?
- el: ?
- docid: Video Hash (same as: `/watch?v=<video_hash>`)
- ns: Most likely "Name Server" because value is `yt` short for `YouTube`
- fexp: Values separated by commas, no idea but seem to start with 23-24 in most cases.
- cl: ?
- seq: Sequence number for packets
- cbr: Client Browser (Chrome, Firefox)
- cbrver: Client Browser version (version of Chrome or Firefox)
- c: Client, so if website is open, this will be `WEB`. Mobile might have something else.
- cver: Client Version `major.YYMMDD.minor.patch`
- cplayer: Client Player, Kind of player used. `UNIPLAYER` for web.
- cos: Client OS, Windows/Linux/Mac
- cosver: Client OS version, `10.0` will be `Windows 10` (in combination with `cos`)
- cplatform: Client Platform: eg. `DESKTOP`
- cmt: ? But not always present
- vps: ?
- user_intent: ?
- bwm: ? But all following values seem related, they are always close together
- bwe: ? Always seem to increase once page is open, so maybe time user has watched the video?
- bat: ?
- vis: ?
- bh: ?
- df: ?

Hope this will help the next person and maybe someone can fill in the blanks.